# Usage function not working as expected

Tags: bash, function, command-line-arguments, conditional-statements

I am writing a quick function to display some help type information however it always runs regardless of whether an argument is given or not:

```
help(){
     if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
     echo ''
     echo '########################################################'
     echo ''
     echo 'Argument to run run name must be given: ./report.sh Name'
     echo ''
     echo 'Name can be:'
     echo ''
     ALLNAMES=$(awk -F'|' '{print $1}' $CONFIGFILE)
     echo "$ALLNAMES"
     echo ''
     echo '########################################################'
     echo ''
     exit 1
     fi

}
```

From what I have research so far the conditional statement is correct and I am simply passing the argument like:

scriptname.sh argument1

The same result is given whether an argument is given or not.

Comment: As this look like a function , `$#` refers to the amount of arguments passed to the function, not the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the arguments to the function as well, or perhaps call the function:

```
help "$@"
```

As another note it's better to use a different name for your function since `help` is already used for a builtin.